# Why does the collapsed-animation not work in vue3?

Tags: css, vuejs3

Why does the transition animation not work in vue3js? I can not see any animation. I am using this library https://github.com/ivanvermeyen/vue-collapse-transition

```
<template>
  <nav class="navbar color-dark section-padding">
    <span :class="this.$route.meta.connect ? 'navbar-toggler' : ''">
      <button class="border-0 navbar" @click="open()">
        <img :src="navgridImg" style="height: 26px; margin: 1vw" />
      </button>
    </span>

    <CollapseTransition >
      <div v-show="show" :class="showClass" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        jdlkajdlsajdlsjdlskajdlsakjdlsajjdlkajd
        lsajdlsjdlskajdlsakjdlsajjdlkajdlsajdlsjdlska
        jdlsakjdlsajjdlkajdlsajdlsjdlskajdlsakj
        dlsajjdlkajdlsajdlsjdlskajdlsakjdlsaj
      </div>
    </CollapseTransition>
  </nav>
</template>
<script>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  
  import { CollapseTransition } from "vue-collapse-transition"

  export default {
    components: { CollapseTransition,  },
    setup() {
      const show = ref(false)
      const showClass = ref('collapse navbar-collapse')

      const open = () => {
        show.value = !show.value
      }

      return {
        show,
```

i think i am doing like the documentation pretty much its the same, its very simple but does not worked, i dont know what is happening

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@ivanv/vue-collapse-transition is a package for Vue 2 and will not work with Vue 3. You can see the version under the header on the NPM page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ivanv/vue-collapse-transition

I would recommend looking into Vue3 transitions: https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html

You should not need a dependency just for a collapse animation ;)
Here is an example of a collapse animation using the built in Vue3 transition.

```
<template>
  <button @click="openClose">open/close</button>
  <Transition name="collapse">
    <div class="collapsableDiv" v-if="isShow">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In convallis
      blandit congue. Etiam id porttitor eros. Interdum et malesuada fames ac
      ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean ut convallis dui, vitae vehicula
      lacus. Phasellus id blandit urna. Phasellus molestie ex ut sagittis
      scelerisque. Quisque eleifend dui eu quam tempor, a finibus augue
      scelerisque.
    </div>
  </Transition>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
const isShow = ref(false);
const openClose = () => {
  isShow.value = !isShow.value;
};
</script>
<style>
.collapsableDiv {
  background-color: rgb(189, 189, 189);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 250px;
}
.collapse-enter-active {
  animation: collapse reverse 500ms ease;
}
.collapse-leave-active {
  animation: collapse 500ms ease;
}
@keyframes collapse {
  from {
    max-height: 200px;
  }
  to {
    max-height: 0px;
  }
}
</style>
```

Edit: This animation is better due to not being dependent on max-height, it uses scaleY() instead. Also fixes issue where animation reverse is delayed due to significant higher max-height than actual element height.

```
<style>
.collapsableDiv {
  background-color: rgb(189, 189, 189);
  width: 250px;
  transform-origin: top;
}
.collapse-enter-active {
  animation: collapse reverse 500ms ease;
}
.collapse-leave-active {
  animation: collapse 500ms ease;
}
@keyframes collapse {
  from {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
</style>
```

Cheers :)

Comment: how can i apply the reverse to close, i mean open and close?

Comment: to uncollapse it take long time to apply, how can i solve that?

Comment: I have added a second css example that should fix your delay issue. Cherrs :)

Comment: Hey there! I know this post is a bit old, but I really love this solution. I have a question though about stacking them. The animation is a bit jumpy when opening one and closing another. Do you have any ideas on how to fix that?

I made a codesandbox testing this out if you could take a look that would be another huge help!
https://codesandbox.io/s/qanda-e8dwlr?file=/src/components/QandA.vue
Cheers for the help either way